# While Connecting to remote server I am getting Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication

Tags: java, ssl, server

While connecting to Remote server sometimes I am getting Warning:

```
no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
```

I have seen this warning in `ssl debug`.

Is it server side trust store issue or client side Key store issue?